# Add validation only for capital letter and numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

If user have used small letter in the field then validation is working like

```
aBCD1234
```

Not working means form will not submit

```
ABCD1234
```

Now user will submit the form.

Comment: Do you mean you want to prevent the form submitting if the input contains lower case characters?

Comment: user toUpperCase() function to check uppercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" />
```

Comment: The main issue with this is that if you try to go back and type in the middle (eg. to fix a typo) then it will boot you to the end again, making for very bad UX.

Answer (score 4):

No need to use JavaScript (and especially not jQuery):

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Z0-9]{8}" />
```

Adjust the pattern as needed, but this will stop form submission of invalid input, *even when JavaScript is disabled*. It's also simpler to program.

MDN Doc on HTML pattern attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern

Comment: @t_l Nice edit. Thanks for bringing my answer up-to-date :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `return isValid();` in the `onclick` event of the `submit` button:

`<input type="button" onclick="return isValid();" />`

The `isValid` function is described well in @janaspage's answer

Comment: Done! (y) Can I ask the same to you, too? Cheers