# Form validation formatting help! (No uppercase, no numbers, no spaces, no special symbols..)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a basic form validation right now in Javascript right now. How do I format it so that whatever is typed in the input field MUST be:

- Uppercase
- No spaces
- No more than 5 characters
- None of the following special symbols: !@#$%^&*()-_+=][{}|’”:;?/><,~`
- No numbers

**Javascript:**

```
function stockValidate() {
  let x = document.getElementById("inputText3").value;
  let text;
  if FORMATTING HERE {
    text = "Input not valid";
    document.getElementById("inputText3").value = '';
  } else {
    text = "Input OK";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-auto">
<input type="text" id="inputText3" class="form-control" aria-describedby="TextHelpInline" placeholder="e.g. AAPL"/>
</div>


<div class="col-auto">
<button id="inputTextBtn3" class="btn set-btn" onclick="stockValidate()">Add</button>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: uppercase condition: `if (x.toUpperCase() == x)`

Comment: contains spaces condition: `if (x.includes(' '))`

Comment: length condition: `if (x.length > 5)`

Comment: special chars condition: const format = /[ `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/; if (format.test(x))

Comment: numbers condition: `if (/\d/.test(x))`

Comment: Thanks so much @GrafiCode , is there a way for me to add all these conditions into one function? Or do I have to create a specific function for each of these conditions?

Comment: well you could create one validation function containing all those IFs, which returns true or false depending on all conditions. I'm pretty sure there are better ways to approach this, too bad I'm not an expert on regular expressions.

Comment: @GrafiCode Thanks, your answers helped. I have it working now! Can you please reply to the post so I can mark yours as the best answer?

Comment: Glad it worked, I think it's best if you self-answer it, showing your validation function. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

I would try that way of solving the issue:

[Add validation only for capital letter and numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838603/add-validation-only-for-capital-letter-and-numbers)

Since you included your html code I would even call the way using the pattern-attribute the simple way to do this validation.

PS: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: Thanks for the info! This might be a bit too simple for my application. I didn't know about patterns in HTML though, nice to learn something new!

Answer (score 1):

As per @Graficode's tips, here is the final code:

```
function stockValidate() {

var specialChars = /[`!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,<>\/?~]/;

  let x = document.getElementById("inputText3").value;
  let text;
    if (x.toUpperCase() != x) {
      document.getElementById('demo').style.display = "block";
      text = "Stock symbol must be uppercase";
      document.getElementById("inputText3").value = '';
    }
        else if (x === '') {
        document.getElementById('demo').style.display = "block";  
        text = "No blanks"
        }

        else if (x.includes(' ')) {
        text = "No spaces";
        document.getElementById('demo').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("inputText3").value = ''; 
        }

        else if (x.length > 5) {
          document.getElementById('demo').style.display = "block";
        text = "No more than 5 characters";
        document.getElementById("inputText3").value = ''; 
        }

        else if (/\d/.test(x)) {
          document.getElementById('demo').style.display = "block";
        text = "No numbers allowed";
        document.getElementById("inputText3").value = ''; 
        }    

        else if (specialChars.test(x)) {
          document.getElementById('demo').style.display = "block";
        text = "No special characters allowed";
        document.getElementById("inputText3").value = ''; 
        } 

        else {
          text = "Input OK";
          document.getElementById('demo').style.display = "none";
        }
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
        }
```